# XHR doesn't appear to fire on transition with Ember

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js, xmlhttprequest, ember-data

Basic Ember app using an API i've written in Laravel. I have an index page showing all products, I generate edit links and when I visit the edit link none of the data is being returned from the model. Looking in the console it appears no XHR request is being made. If I force refresh then the XHR fires and the data appears.

```
// Init App
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    rootElement: '#myapp-ember'
});

// Declare routes
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource("products",function(){
        this.route('new');
        this.route("edit", { path: "/:id/edit" });
    });
});

// Model 
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    brand: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr('string'),
    type: DS.attr('string')
});

// Declare Data Store so Ember knows we're using Ember Data to handle our Model
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11
});

// set our API namespace
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
    namespace: 'api/v1'
});

// forward from "/" to "/products"
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function(){
        this.transitionTo('products');
    }
});

App.ProductsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Product.find();
    }
});

App.ProductsEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return App.Product.find(params.id);
    }
});
```

Main HTML file here:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products">
    <h3>All Products 
    {{#linkTo "products.new" classNames="btn btn-small pull-right"}}<i class="icon-plus"></i> Add Product{{/linkTo}}
    </h3>
    {{ outlet }}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products/index">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Category</th>               
                <th>Type</th>
                <th width="100">Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        {{#each product in controller }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{product.title}}</td>
                <td>{{product.brand}}</td>
                <td>{{product.category}}</td>
                <td>{{product.type}}</td>
                <td>
                    {{#linkTo "products.edit" product.id classNames="btn btn-small pull-info"}}edit{{/linkTo}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}        
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products/new">
    <h2>new</h2>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products/edit">
    <h2>edit</h2>
    {{ title }}
</script>
```

Like I said, index page (that redirects to /products) is showing all data as expected, links are created as they should be but when I land on the /products/ID/edit page I only see the `<h2>edit</h2>` until I refresh which causes the product title to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons that the ajax request is not firing:

1. when using `{{linkTo theRoute theObject}}`, the `model` hook on `theRoute` is never called, because you already have the object to link to it! Instead, the routes model is *set* to be `theObject`
2. Even if the model hook were called and it called `App.Product.find(params.id);`, it would return the original object, because you have loaded it into the datastore with `App.Product.find()`.

The solution is either:

1. Return all data in your list action, rather than just e.g. name and id. The list you get back from /products should have all the data for each item that you'd get from /products/1, products/2 etc, just all in a big list
2. Use a related model, e.g. `ProductData`, and use a relation to load in the product data when you need it.

With this in mind, your `{{linkTo}}` should have just `product` instead of `product.id` in it.

The last piece of the puzzle is in your route definition - you have used the param `:id`, instead of `:product_id` which is what ember expects. Either change it to `:product_id`, or add an appropriate `serialize` hook to your ProductsEditRoute